# upgrade angular john papa modular project from 1.2.28 to 1.4.4 error

Tags: angularjs

I install the modular project, all packages, and run fine.
When I upgrade the angular from 1.2.28 to 1.4.4 (I need to use some new features and because the dependency from other libraries), an error appeared:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.core due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blocks.exception due to:
Error: [$injector:strictdi] config is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the AngularJS Migration guides. I would recommend migrating from 1.2 to 1.3 first, and then from 1.3 to 1.4.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: Thanks, I create my own structure, which is easier.